# How to define records for a variable length file in cobol

Tags: file, cobol, mainframe

I have a file where the record format Variable Block (VB). The Record length is 225, and the Block size 27998.

How do I declare this in my COBOL program?. I am currently getting file status code 39 which means

> The OPEN statement was unsuccessful because a conflict has been detected between the fixed file attributes and the attributes specified for the file in the program. (Attributes that are checked are organization, index keys (primary and alternate), block size and maximum record size)

Here is my current file definition:

```
SELECT 
   INPUT-FILE ASSIGN TO INFILE1 
   ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL 
   FILE STATUS IS RETURN-CODE-IN
. 



FD INPUT-FILE 
   RECORDING MODE IS V 
   RECORD IS VARYING FROM 1 TO 221 
   BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS
.
```

Comment: Please show us your file control statement that you have tried. Also show your FD statement for the records contained within this data set (not a file).

Comment: FILE CONTROL:  

SELECT                     INPUT-FILE
ASSIGN TO               INFILE1
ORGANIZATION IS   LINE SEQUENTIAL
FILE STATUS IS       RETURN-CODE-IN.

FD STATEMENT IS:

FD INPUT-FILE
RECORDING MODE IS V
RECORD IS VARYING FROM 1 TO 221
BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS.

Answer (score 4):

```
   FD  INPUT-FILE
       Record Varying 1 To 221
         Depending INPUT-FILE-REC-LEN
       Block 0
       Recording V.
   01  INPUT-FILE-REC       PIC X(221).
```

[...]

```
   01  WORK-AREAS.
       05  INPUT-FILE-REC-LEN   PIC 9(004) COMP-5 VALUE 0.
```

After a successful READ operation INPUT-FILE-REC-LEN will contain the length of the record which has been read.

Answer (score 0):

The `RECORD VARYING clause` was introduced in COBOL 85 to define variable length records. The `RECORDING MODE clause` was always a non-standard extension for the same use.

Because the `RECORD VARYING clause` is sufficient, the `RECORDING MODE clause` is redundant, and, therefore, should be removed.